# How can I get stumbleupon's database of websites?

Tags: php, database

I'd like to get all the sites which have been added to Stumbleupon.
I'd like to add PHP. Is there any API?

Comment: oh come on, the database is out there for everyone to see, stumbleupon doesn't actually makes those websites.

Comment: The pretty diamonds at the jewelry store are out there for everyone to see, too.

Comment: the content of cnn\abc ... is also, you have know idea what copyright is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no API for this (and most sites would be pretty leery of giving that huge a data set away, anyways).

Comment: OK, here's what I have found. If you go to http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/ you can visit sites individually by clicking the 'Stumble' button. Is there any way to do it via a script, so that we can get the urls, which can then be saved in a database?

Comment: Sure, you could do that. They'll probably ban you from abusing their servers, though, and chances are it'd take years to do even if they didn't.